# Manipulate required to manage 3 parameters one which is a function

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, manipulate

Let *f*(*x*)=*ax*(1-*x*) and I=[0,1]. Then *f*(I) is contained in I for 0≤α≤4. Take any *x*0 in I and study the iterations *x*1=*f*(*x*0) etc. Convergence or otherwise around the one or two fixed points (depending on *a*) is of interest. If  *a*≤1 then convergence is easy. The next case is 1≤*a*≤2 is harder but straightforward. 2≤*a*≤3 is also ok but different to the previous case. Now it gets mad. For 3≤*a*≤4  if a is not too much bigger than 3, then the sequence oscillates between its two fixed points and I can demonstrate this. But for *a* near 4, it becomes chaotic and defies easy analysis.
With *x*, *a* as above and *n* being the number of iterations, I cannot make Manipulate manage all three.The one of particular interest is '*a*'. I have read the "With" command but I am not that familiar with it. This is the best I have come up with.

```
a = 3.5
f[x_] :=  a x (1 - x)
Manipulate[ListPlot[NestList[f, x, n]], {x, 0, 1}, {n, 0, 1000, 1}]
```

which means I have to change the 'a' manually.
I hope I have motivated this problem and it is not so evident that I can find it in the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need `SaveDefinitions -> True`?[Like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dqHaj.png) pictrue.

Comment: Many thanks. That works provided I action  the sliders in the right order. The point is, it gives me what I need. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One way to put the whole thing into the Manipulate is to define f as having two parameters, x and a.

```
f[x_, a_] := a x (1 - x);
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[NestList[f[#, a] &, x, n]], {x, 0, 1}, {n, 0, 1000, 1}, {a, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: Many, many thanks. That's great. I tried something like that but it's the # feature that I'll have to learn. It works perfectly now thanks to you!